# How to reload item of SWT when anew set?

Tags: java, swt

I am trying to display a dynamic `toolTipText`. My code as follows:

```
...
public TrayItem item;
...

public static void main(String args[]) {
    ....
    ....
    TrayItem item = new TrayItem(tray, SWT.NONE);
    item.setToolTipText("My string");
    ...
    ...
}
```

This code is run successfully. But there is no change on , if I set new string in another function as follows:

```
mainWindow.item.setToolTipText("My string -- " + getStatus().getMessage());
```

How to reload item of SWT, when anew set?

Comment: Are you calling setToolTipText() from the same thread in both cases?

Comment: No, second setToolTipText() is called from different thread.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You must call setToolTipText() from the thread that created the TrayItem.

From the Eclipse API documentation:

```
public void setToolTipText(String string)
Throws:
... 
    SWTException -
    ...
        ERROR_THREAD_INVALID_ACCESS - if not called from the thread that created the receiver
```

One way to forward calls to the user-interface thread is to use `Display.asyncExec( Runnable )`. For example:

```
    Display.getDefault().asyncExec(new Runnable() {
        public void run() {
               mainWindow.item.setToolTipText( "My string -- " + getStatus().getMessage() );
            }});
```